# Programmatically close the Browser from Linux Terminal in Chrome OS?

Tags: linux, bash, google-chrome, chromebook

I am trying to write a bash script that will automate some activity in the Browser on my Chromebook, and part of the workflow involves closing the Browser. I can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this.

pkill -9 [PID] doesn't work -- the Chrome Browser doesn't show up when listed, and it can't even be killed from task manager.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't show up when listed?

Answer (score 0):

The argument to pkill is not a PID.
"pkill chrome" would work.

```
$ /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable &
[1] 11653
$
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  264 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
11879 pts/1    00:00:04 chrome
11883 pts/1    00:00:00 cat
11884 pts/1    00:00:00 cat
11894 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11895 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11897 pts/1    00:00:00 nacl_helper
11900 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11919 pts/1    00:00:01 chrome
11921 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11922 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11936 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11944 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
11945 pts/1    00:00:01 chrome
12067 pts/1    00:00:00 chrome
12097 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
$ 
$ pkill chrome
$ 
[1]+  Done                    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
  264 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
12100 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
$
```